# scoped and find_within

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

Iam using geokit-rails (http://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails branch gem).
I like to build a scope like

```
a = MyModel.scoped
a = a.limit(10).scoped
a = a.find_within(10,:origin => [mylat,mylng]).scoped
a = a.where(:visible => true)
a = a.paginate(:page => @params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

But this does't work - after find the query will fired. The scopes .origin and .within (described in the documentation of geokit-rails) don't work.

In rails2 I'd used rayn bates scope_builder and this do work until the update on rails3.
Cause I'm not such a advanced programmer I'm not able do implement my own scope into geokit-rails.

Does anyone have a idea how i prevent ActiveRecord to fire the query on the find_within method?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the solution is here: http://github.com/Olli/geokit-rails/commit/7df7316870045def9eaaf640d4a068853c8d1962 
Have Fun :)